# How to simulate Signal-Noise Ratio?

Tags: r, simulation, signal-processing

I have a vector of simulated data:

```
data = c(0.47, 0.45, 0.30, 1.15, 0.82, 0.38, 0.51, 1.36, 1.72, 0.36)
```

I've been adding noise to this by generating random numbers centered at 0 with different standard deviations:

```
noise = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
data_wNoise = data + noise
```

I've been setting the standard deviation arbitrarily (between 0.001 and 1.5). Is there a better way to simulate this by setting a specific signal-to-noise ratio? I don't know anything about the power of the signal in the data.

Answer (score 7):

Given a model
$$
Y = f(X) + \varepsilon
$$

The signal to noise ratio can be defined as (ref. [ESL10](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)) :

$$
\frac{Var(f(X))}{Var(\varepsilon)}
$$

To generate data with a specific signal to noise ratio:

```
signal_to_noise_ratio = 4
data = c(0.47, 0.45, 0.30, 1.15, 0.82, 0.38, 0.51, 1.36, 1.72, 0.36)
noise = rnorm(data) # generate standard normal errors
k <- sqrt(var(data)/(signal_to_noise_ratio*var(noise)))
data_wNoise = data + k*noise
```

Comment: In the code, k is a value dependent on the noise, thus, the generated data_wNoise is not independent. Is this a problem?